# Que tiene malo este Trigger? de MySQL

Tags: mysql

ME DA ERROR  de Sintexis lo estoy haciendo igual que como creo se hace con SQL server 2008 R2 pero ocupo hacerlo para MySQL ¿Cual es el error? Si alguien me ayuda lo agradezco de antemano.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Actualize_Nombres
AFTER INSERT
ON sr_escalas_detalle FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE 
@id INT,
@id_escala INT,
@orden  INT,
@puntos INT,
@id_producto1 INT,
@id_producto2 INT,
@id_producto3 INT,
@id_producto4 INT,
@id_producto5 INT,
@titulo_esp varchar (max),
@titulo_eng varchar (max),
@titulo_bra varchar (max),
@descripcion_esp varchar (max),
@descripcion_eng varchar (max),
@descripcion_bra varchar (max)


SET @id_producto1 = (SELECT id_producto1 FROM INSERTED)
SET @id_producto2 = (SELECT id_producto2 FROM INSERTED)
SET @id_producto3 = (SELECT id_producto3 FROM INSERTED)
SET @id_producto4 = (SELECT id_producto4 FROM INSERTED)
SET @id_producto5 = (SELECT id_producto5 FROM INSERTED)

SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto1)
SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto2)
SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto3)
SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto4)
SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto5)

SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto1)
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto2)
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto3)
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto4)
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto5)

SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto1)
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto2)
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto3)
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto4)
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = id_producto5)


UPDATE `shaiyar1_almacen`.`sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE id_producto1 = @id_producto1
UPDATE `shaiyar1_almacen`.`sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE id_producto2 = @id_producto2
UPDATE `shaiyar1_almacen`.`sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE id_producto3 = @id_producto3
UPDATE `shaiyar1_almacen`.`sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE id_producto4 = @id_producto4
UPDATE `shaiyar1_almacen`.`sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE id_producto5 = @id_producto5

END
```

Comment: el primer detalle es que las variables en mysql se declaran `SET @titulo` pues como tu mismo mencionas la sintáxis que usas es de SQL Server y esa no es idéntica a MySQL

Comment: COMO asi? no entendi por favor me muestras?

Comment: si, en SQL Server usas `DECLARE @name = algo` pero en MySQL es `SET @name=algo`

Comment: por que no publicas la respuesta agregando por que la sentencia INSERTED no anda en MySQL ya que quiero usarla pero veo que en MySQL no funciona my SQL lo toma como una tabla.

Comment: necesitp antes tener claro una respuesta para el uso de `INSERTED` pues no lo conocía

Comment: New.variable = INSERTED jajajajaj es que tampoco lo conocia bien ahora tengo otro problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la Primera Parte era

```
SET @Variable = 'sentencia'
```

en la segunda respuesta seria:

el valor de `INSERTED` en SQL server  es igual que  `New.Variable` en MySQL