# Por que no me hace UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de Crear un Trigger para MYSQL pero este NO me deja Insert en tabla ni actualizar (Nota: E instalado el trigger desde Navicat NO se si tenga algo que ver pero si realizo la consulta para crear el triger Exito si me deja PERO si la hago desde phpmyadmin el resultado es la tercera consulta y tampoco deja editar)
alguien me ayuda por favor? el error que me sale es el de la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TRIGGER Actualize_Nombres
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
ON sr_escalas_detalle FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN


SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1);
SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto2);
SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto3);
SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto4);
SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto5);

SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1);
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto2);
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto3);
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto4);
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto5);

SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1);
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto2);
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto3);
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto4);
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto5);


UPDATE `sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE New.id_producto1 = New.id_producto1;
UPDATE `sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE New.id_producto2 = New.id_producto2;
UPDATE `sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE New.id_producto3 = New.id_producto3;
UPDATE `sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE New.id_producto4 = New.id_producto4;
UPDATE `sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE New.id_producto5 = New.id_producto5;

END
```

Misma consulta editada sigue con el error de la imagen:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Actualize_Nombres
AFTER INSERT
ON sr_escalas_detalle FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

SET @titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1);
SET @titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1);
SET @titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1);


UPDATE `sr_escalas_detalle` SET  titulo_esp = @titulo_esp,titulo_eng = @titulo_eng,titulo_bra = @titulo_bra ,descripcion_esp = '<br>',descripcion_eng = '<br>',descripcion_bra = '<br>' WHERE New.id_producto1 = New.id_producto1;

END
```

3 Creado desde phpmyadmin
Despues de Volver a editar trate con esta Consulta e ir descartando pero sigue sin dejar Insertar registros. si lo instalo desde navicat deja instalar pero no inserta registros y si lo hago desde phpMyAdmin NO deja crear el trigger y por supuesto que sin el trigger si inserta datos.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER Actualize_Nombres
AFTER INSERT
ON sr_escalas_detalle FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

UPDATE `sr_escalas_detalle` SET  
titulo_esp = (SELECT nombre_esp FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1 LIMIT 1),
titulo_eng = (SELECT nombre_eng FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1 LIMIT 1),
titulo_bra = (SELECT nombre_bra FROM sr_productos WHERE id = New.id_producto1 LIMIT 1),
descripcion_esp = '<br>',
descripcion_eng = '<br>',
descripcion_bra = '<br>' 
WHERE New.id_producto1 = New.id_producto1;




END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

PD intento Insertar esto:

```
INSERT INTO `sr_escalas_detalle` (`id`, `id_escala`, `orden`, `puntos`, `id_producto1`, `id_producto2`, `id_producto3`, `id_producto4`, `id_producto5`, `titulo_esp`, `titulo_eng`, `titulo_bra`, `descripcion_esp`, `descripcion_eng`, `descripcion_bra`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '110000', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

la extructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `sr_escalas_detalle` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_escala` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `orden` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `puntos` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto1` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto2` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto3` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto4` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto5` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `titulo_esp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titulo_eng` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titulo_bra` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion_esp` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion_eng` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion_bra` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: estaria bueno saber que tratas de hacer con este trigger, ya que todas las varialbes se llaman igual, haces un update (y preguntas porque haces un update) y no se entiende a que queres llegar

Comment: Acabas de repetir la pregunta? tenes suficiente reputacion como para saber como funciona el sitio... ademas la original la modificaste poniendo la respuesta en la pregunta?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Que tiene malo este Trigger? de MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/206959/que-tiene-malo-este-trigger-de-mysql)

Comment: Amigo hay claramente dice por que NO HACE ACTUALIZAR o UPDATE que parte de NO hace no se entiende amigo por que la verdad yo soy novato en el area disculpe usted

Comment: Si bien es parecido el trigues la pregunta es distinta en un comienzo eran variables despues el INSERTED ambos los respondi esta es total mente distinta pregunta ya que el detalle es que la consulta contenia tres errores

Comment: Empecemos por ordenar tu cuenta.. tenes montones de preguntas sin respuesta aceptada. Acepta una respuesta, agrega la solucion o elimina la pregunta. Aparte de eso, esta pregunta parece un duplicado exacto de la que hiciste hace una hora. Siguiendo con el tema, dice que no hace update, pero las instrucciones son update. Si no hace update, podrias aclarar que esta pasando, que error recibis, o que esperas que pase y no pasa? lo que veo es que definis exactamente la misma variable montones de veces, y la usas para actualizar muchos registros de una tabla

Comment: realiza muchas asignaciones de valores en `@titulo_esp`, `@titulo_eng`, `@titulo_bra`
por lo tanto el valor que recibe de las tres variables será el último independientemente. Cuando realiza la actualización en las tablas quizas provoca conflicto de registro por duplicidad, aunque para confirmar esto, deberias de mostrarnos la estructura de tu tabla por acá.

Comment: OK amigo si bien debo selecionar la respuesta USTED no coloco dicha respuesta para yo poder votar por ella me ubiera encantado amigo de hecho usted respondio bien la primera pregunta pero me temo que los comentarios no cuentan como respuestas ¿o si?

Comment: Me referia a todas las preguntas que tenes en el sitio en general, desconozco si alguna respuesta es mia. La respuesta a esta pregunta esta en el error, que te manda mysql, no podes hacer update de la tabla donde el trigger esta haciendo update.

Comment: ok hermano en que seccion  busco las que no vote? lol solo pregunto a veces se me pasa eso de responder disculpe

Comment: Es muy importante marcar las respuestas correctas cuando lo son. La gente se toma el tiempo en analizar tu problema y lo menos que se puede hacer por ellos es darles un gracias de esa forma. Ademas, la proxima persona que vea la pregunta, sabe que esa es una respuesta que funciona. Vuelve a revisar el [tour] por favor. Las preguntas, las tenes en tu perfil. Toda aquella que no tenga un cuadro verde, no tiene una respuesta correcta marcada

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Controlar que se inserte todo en mayúscula](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195874/controlar-que-se-inserte-todo-en-may%c3%bascula)

Comment: si pero ni yo hice ese post no se ni que tiene que ver con el mio de verdad no entiendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta no la sabia es que un trigger no actualiza la misma tabla que se ve afectada

Comment: Es exactamente lo que dice el mensaje de error.